# Python - Trying to subtract time from an input(unsupported operand type)

Tags: python

I'm trying to subtracted 2 minutes from a value input from a website:
I keep getting an error:
line 35, in actual_time
delay_time = set_alarm_timer - timedelta(minutes = 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'

code is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
driver=webdriver.Edge(executable_path='C:\Python27amd64\msedgedriver')
vars = {}
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def actual_time():
    global set_alarm_timer
    global delay_time
    set_alarm_timer = f"{hour.get()}:{min.get()}:{sec.get()}"
    delay_time = set_alarm_timer - timedelta(minutes = 2)
alarm()

clock = Tk()
clock.title("Canyon Oaks CC Start Reservation Clock")
clock.geometry("400x200")
time_format=Label(clock, text= "Enter time in 24 hour format!", 
fg="red",bg="black",font="Arial").place(x=60,y=120)
addTime = Label(clock,text = "Hour  Min   Sec",font=60).place(x = 110)
setYourAlarm = Label(clock,text = "When to start Reservation",fg="blue",relief = "solid",font= ("Helevetica",7,"bold")).place(x=0, y=29)

hour = StringVar()
min = StringVar()
sec = StringVar()

hourTime= Entry(clock,textvariable = hour,bg = "pink",width = 15).place(x=110,y=30)
minTime= Entry(clock,textvariable = min,bg = "pink",width = 15).place(x=150,y=30)
secTime = Entry(clock,textvariable = sec,bg = "pink",width = 15).place(x=200,y=30)

submit = Button(clock,text = "Set Alarm",fg="red",width = 10,command = actual_time).place(x =110,y=70)

clock.mainloop()
```

Comment: `set_alarm_timer` is a string. You can't do math operations with strings. Also next time post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: Also `new = datetime.datetime.strptime(set_alarm_timer, '%H:%M:%S')` and `delay_time = new - timedelta(minutes=2)` should also do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
    set_alarm_timer = f"{hour.get()}:{min.get()}:{sec.get()}"
    delay_time = set_alarm_timer - timedelta(minutes = 2)
```

You set `set_alarm_timer` to a string. You subtract a timedelta from the string. The error message tells you exactly that: "cannot use the operator `-` with the types `str` and `typedelta". What did you expect to happen?

Instead just create another `timedelta` using the values from `hour`, `min`, and `sec`, instead of a string:

```
    set_alarm_timer = timedelta(hours=hour.get(), minutes=min.get(), seconds=sec.get())
    delay_time = set_alarm_timer - timedelta(minutes = 2)
```

Comment: Tried that, error:                                                                                         Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\micha\source\repos\makeAReservation\makeAReservation\makeAReservation.py", line 159, in actual_time
    set_alarm_timer = timedelta(hours=hour.get(), minutes=min.get(), seconds=sec.get())
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: str

Comment: Then convert the `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` into numbers. Read the error message.